Unable to Sign in with Google in Android Studio Emulator
Does anyone know what the trick is to sign into Google in Android Studio Emulator?
I have tried to follow every tutorial I can find.

Could not sign in Google account on android emulator with react-native app

Unable to Sign in into with google in Android Studio Emulator(API 30, target - Android 11.0 with Google Play, CPU- x86 )



You need to describe what happens, how is it related to the links you posted, what you actually tried already and what happens. Also, are you behind a proxy?
